# Draw rectangle on picturebox that is showing stream from webcam

Tags: c#, webcam, picturebox

I am currently working on a tracking algorithm using C#. I use a picturebox to display the video streams from the webcam：

```
CameraVideo = new Camera(pbVideo.Handle, pbVideo.Location.X, pbVideo.Location.Y, pbVideo.Size.Width, pbVideo.Size.Height);
CameraVideo.OpenCamera();
```

new I want to use a rectangle to local the object that I am tracking, but I found that the

```
Graphics tg = pbVideo.CreateGraphics();
tg.DrawRectangle(......)
```

cannot show the rectangle that I want. is there anyway to overcome this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the paint event instead of CreateGraphics.  You have to explain what `cannot show the rectangle that I want` means.

Comment: I mean there is no Rectangle shown on the picturebox at all. How do i use paint event, can you give me some code example? thanks very much

Comment: How did you create the pen?

Comment: Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red,3);

Comment: It sounds like your rectangle is getting overwritten when the next frame of the video is displayed.  Does the Camera class have any events that would allow you to do your custom painting after each frame is rendered?